# Logger Issues - Rails Heroku / Foreman in Dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, unicorn, foreman

I seem to have a very odd issue....  I am trying to develop a Rails app to be deployed on Heroku using Unicorn - as such I'm using Foreman in my local development environment to try to replicate production as closely as possible.

As you'd expect, my web/worker processes output to the development.log file in path/to/app/log.  If I navigate to the file, it contains *everything you would expect*.

**However** if I use the command

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

(from the app path), I get log output from **HEROKU**!!  How is this possible?  (e.g.):

```
app[web.1]: [Worker(host:xxxx-xxx-xxx pid:5)] Starting job worker
heroku[web.1]: Idling
heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
app[web.1]: I, [2012-02-19xxx-xxx-xxx #1]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 7 exit 0> worker=0
app[web.1]: I, [2012-02-19xxx-xxx-xxx #1]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 11 exit 0> worker=1
app[web.1]: I, [2012-02-19xxx-xxx-xxx #1]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 14 exit 0> worker=2
app[web.1]: I, [2012-02-19xxx-xxx-xxx #1]  INFO -- : master complete
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
heroku[api]: Release v22 created by brandon@example.com
heroku[api]: Deploy xxxx by randon@example.com
heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
```

This is really annoying as I can't properly see my development log... help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that Foreman's doing.

What happens if you just look at log/development.log? Is it the same?

Do you have any wacky aliases setup that might be causing this?

Comment: You got it!  I didn't know that aliases were recursive (i.e. an alias would call other aliases as opposed to the original command).  That fixed it once I sorted those out. THANKS!

Comment: having this issue right now myself - is there an updated answer?